# Spring boot Apache Camel Quartz JDBC scheduler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I using spring boot with apache camel and I want to create quartz scheduler but when I using this configuration nothing has happened:

```
camel:
    component:
        quartz2:
          properties:
            org:
              quartz:
                scheduler:
                  instanceName: ClusteredSchedular
                  instanceId: AUTO
                threadPool:
                  class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
                  threadCount: 25
                  threadPriority: 5
                jobStore:
                  class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
                  driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
                  dataSource: quartz
                  isClustered: true
                  clusterCheckinInterval: 20000
                dataSource:
                  quartz:
                    driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
                    URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
                    user: test
                    password: test
                    maxConnections: 5
                    validationQuery: select 1 from dual
```

Does anyone have an idea why this configuration doesn't work? Camel only see this configuration from default config

```
    org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: DefaultQuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export: false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy: false
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction: false

org.quartz.threadPool.class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread: true

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold: 60000

org.quartz.jobStore.class: org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to use springboot datasource to enable quartz clustering.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres
    username: postgres
    password: password
  quartz:
    scheduler-name: quartzSchedulernot work anymore
    jobStoreType: jdbc
    startup-delay: PT10S
    wait-for-jobs-to-complete-on-shutdown: true
  properties:
    org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId: AUTO
    org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export: true
    org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 15
    org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5
    org.quartz.threadPool.class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
    org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread: true
    org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
    org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix: QRTZ_
    org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered: true
    org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval: 1000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer this will work perfectly, but I added one more parameter for auto create tabels
  quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: always
      comment-prefix: '#'

Comment: Using a config like this I get `org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: DataSource name not set.` exception. The problem is that it doesn't accept the (multiple in my case) dataSources in spring.jdbc.connections

Comment: if you have multiple datasources, you have to explicit the configuration of quartz to use on or another

Comment: In SpringBoot 2.3.9 and Camel 3.4.3 the above config seems to be ignored and the default quartz config is used. What worked for me is specifying : camel.component.quartz.properties-file=my-quartz.properties.   

But then i have to replicate my spring datasources into this file.    

Example: 
    org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = org.h2.Driver
    org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = ...etc
    org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=myDS 

Would be nice if i could referer to the spring datasource (i have multiple) configured in the application.properties / yml.